# My flask Application authentication is working fine but when I dockerise the whole application using an alpine image the authentication is broken

Tags: docker, flask, apache2, mod-wsgi, flask-login

I have a basic small Flask Application, when run locally the authentication works fine, but when I dockerzise the whole application using an alpine image, the authentication is broken. Even though I enter proper credentials my application logs in but shows an error message which says "Please log in to access this page".

I am using Apache2 as my reverse proxy and httpd:alpine as my docker image.
This is my docker file

```
FROM httpd:2.4.38-alpine

RUN apk --update --no-cache add python3 python3-dev apache2  wget ca-certificates make gcc musl-dev py-pip py-virtualenv

COPY ./app_trac/apache2-vhost.conf conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

RUN sed -i -e 's/^#ServerName.*$/ServerName vacation.ps-office.local:80/' conf/httpd.conf

RUN sed -i -e "s|#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf|Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf|g"  conf/httpd.conf

RUN cd /usr/local/apache2/modules/

RUN mkdir vacation

COPY ./app_trac/requirements.txt htdocs/app/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r htdocs/app/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install mod_wsgi

RUN mod_wsgi-express module-config

RUN chmod -R a+rwx htdocs/app

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["httpd", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

This is my application's load and save user functions, I am using LDAP authentication.

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    if user_id in users:
        return users[user_id]
    return None

@ldap_manager.save_user
def save_user(dn, username, data, memberships):
    user = User(dn = dn, username = username, data = data)
    users[dn] = user
    return user
```

What am I basically doing wrong? I get only authentication issues with the docker. The nginx seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to allow the container to access the LDAP server, when running a container the network access it have is limited.

Maybe this helps you [LDAP authentication in Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825105/ldap-authentication-in-docker-container)

Comment: The application logs in sometimes, but the main problem is the load_user function is not actually loading the user. I get an error message which says "please log in to access this page"

Comment: I do recommend that you debug the code, you can use `pdb` or some remote debug feature on the IDEs like PyCharm to help with this.